# time() safe in mysql doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a little problem safe the current time in Mysql.

The Table have two rows:

1. timestamp - on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
2. A PHP file

Here is my code:

```
$stamp = time();

if (mysqli_connect_errno() == 0){
    $sql = "UPDATE xy SET stamp = '$stamp' WHERE id = '$ID'";
    $erg = $db->query($sql);    
}
```

I have just copy the files from server 1 to server 2, and now it doesnt work on my new Server.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: please provide error messages :

Comment: Don't write mysqli code like that. Use [mysqli_prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), or rewrite to use the standard SQL `current_timestamp`.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' I think that may be just a portion of the OP's code. I doubt that code, will do anything by itself.

Comment: What do you mean your table has two rows, one "timestamp" and the other "A php file"?  Let me assume this is a language problem, and you mean "column" instead of "row".  Your query contains the columns `stamp` and `id` -- neither or which you say are in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are not providing any errors, I am going to just assume this works. 
use mysql's `NOW()` function ?  or  `CURTIME()`, `UTC_TIMESTAMP()`

```
 $sql = "UPDATE xy SET stamp = NOW() WHERE id = '$ID'";
```

Or, just use an error handler like `or die(sprintf("[%d] %s\n", mysqli_connect_errno(), mysqli_connect_error()));`